# Azure-automation: Cannot bind parameter 'Context'

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-automation

I am trying to create new directories in Azure datalake using azure automation powershell workflow.
The code that i have is like this:

```
    $ctx = New-AzStorageContext -ConnectionString $connectionstring

    New-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName -Path $dirname -Directory
```

the error message that I get:

```
New-AzDataLakeGen2Item : Cannot bind parameter 'Context'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext" value of type "Deserialized.Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.IStorageContext
```

I dont know how to solve this error? any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if you give it a try with $ctx.Context instead of $ctx ? It seems that the IStorageContext is one level below reading to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.commands.storage.azurestoragecontext?view=az-ps-latest#properties

Comment: Sadly that didnt work, the error after the change:  Cannot convert the "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext" value of type "System.String" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.IStorageContext. Still thanks for your help,

Comment: Then you might need to use an InlineScript block here - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-powershell-workflow#deserialized-objects

Comment: Wow, thank you alot, it got solved.  Thank you alot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our local environment, We have created a Powershell runbook running with PowerShell Version 5.1.

Using the same above shared cmdlets, we are able to create a new directory in the Azure Data lake storage account. We have used  System managed identity to connect to subscription resources from the automation account.

**Here is the Powershell script that we have used in Automation Account:**

```
 Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process  # Ensures you do not inherit an AzContext in your runbook
 $AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context # Connect to Azure with system-assigned managed identity
$AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext  # set and store context
    
Import-module -name Az.Storage

$ctx=New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "<strgaccountName>" -StorageAccountKey "<storageaccountKey>"
New-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem "testfiler" -Path "dir1/dir2" -Directory
```

**Here is the Sample output for reference:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks that worked for me aswell. Is there a difference in powershell runbook and normal powershell automation in azure.

Comment: @YusufD, PowerShell Runbook is one of the runbook supported type in Azure Automation.Azure Automation delivers a cloud-based automation, operating system updates, and configuration service that supports consistent management across your Azure and non-Azure environments. It includes process automation, configuration management, update management, shared capabilities, and heterogeneous features.
For more information about Azure Automation, you refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/) documentation.