# Connect to azure blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am using the below powershell script to connect to azure datalake storage gen2 using my credentials for development and after deployment use managed identity credentials.

**Code:**

```
try {
        $AzStorageContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context;
    }
catch{
        $AzStorageContext = (Connect-AzAccount).context;
    }

$AzStorageContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzStorageContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzStorageContext
Get-AzStorageContainer -Name 'MyContainer' -Context $AzStorageContext
```

The error I run into is

**Error:**

```
Get-AzStorageContainer : Cannot bind parameter 'Context'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.Core.PSAzureContext" value of type 
"Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.Models.Core.PSAzureContext" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.IStorageContext".
```

Answer (score 0):

Connecting Azure storage with system-assigned managed identity using Power Shell

```
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity).context

$AzureContext = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzureContext.Subscription -DefaultProfile $AzureContext
```

For more information refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71031069/azure-automation-cannot-bind-parameter-context) thread by VenkateshDodda-MSFT

Comment: Hi @bhanunagasaiVamsi-MT, I run into a similar issue with runbook, I see completed message but get this error at the same time.                                            
 `This request is not authorized to perform this operation.

Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation.)
ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationFailure</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation.`